# Is it acceptable to create two actions and two reducers to fetch same data for two different components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two components that are rendered together in one page, both components receive same fetched data, i have an action and a reducer that takes over fetching data and one component has **filter** and **sort** functionalities, so filtering or sorting data in that component affect the data rendered in the other component.

I don't know if storing data twice in state tree is a good idea, and if i can do this, how can i achieve that in general?

**Code**

**Action**

```
const fetchData = (data, filters, sortBy) => {
    if (filters && filters.length > 0 ) {
       data = data.filter (......)
    }
    if (sortBy) {
      data.sort(....)
    }
    //the action
    return {
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: data
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA:
            return action.payload
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**App**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    data: state.data,
    filters: state.filters,
    sortBy: state.sortBy,
  });
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadData: (filters, sortBy) => {
      fetch('data').then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
        dispatch(fetchData(json.data, filters, sortBy));
      }).catch(err => 'error fetching data');
    }
  };
}
```

The data fetched go to two components in the same page, filtering and sorting dispatch the same action that fetch data, **fetchData**

how to modify that code to make a separation between the two components??

Comment: It would be really useful to share some code samples for anyone who'd like to answer your question. 
In general, as long as you are following the standard redux pattern, it really doesn't matter how many reducers you are using to manage your store. For two actions to work on the same data object, you just need to make sure one happened after another, either synchronously or by separate user interactions.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at [reselect-library](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). It solves all the issues that you are facing by creating memoized selectors.

Comment: @humanbean i checked the library and found no relation to my question??

Comment: @CodeEagle, you wish to feed the data after filtering and sorting based on the user's selection, right?

If that is the case then you can create one selector which takes in both filter and sort values from redux and then returns a list after applying them on your already fetched and stored data. 

So it is no longer needed to fetchData once user changes the filter or sort variables.

In short, fetch data and store it, read in sort and filter and store it. Now subscribe your component with a selector which returns data after applying filter and sort.

Comment: @humanbean thank you ..the problem is that i have 2 components in the same page that need to be fed with the same data and each one has filtering and sorting functionality..do you think this would work??

Comment: @CodeEagle I suppose it should work, but instead you will have to store the values as props and pass it back to your selector.
[Here](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors) have a look.